# LZMA compression settings details

Tags: lzma

I really need to know what each lzma parameter (mf, fb, lp, ...) means. I could not find any good documentation in the internet. I need details of this algorithm. the most detailed one is:
http://www.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/switches/method.htm
I would appreciate any help.

Best wishes,
Shadi.

Comment: Are you trying to implement lzma, or just use an existing tool?

Comment: I want to make some changes in lzma source code. In addition, I want to be able to set parameters to optimize the speed or compression ratio. So, I need to know details about the algorithm and its parameters.
Thanks.

Comment: @Shadi : did you check [method.htm](http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method.htm)?

Answer (score 27):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lzma) `no complete natural language specification of the compressed format seems to exist`. However configuration settings are specified.

During my work with `LZMA SDK` I discovered the following compression settings `CLzmaEncProps` and `CLzma2EncProps` structure types:

### *LZMA Options:*

### level

- Description: The compression level.
- Range: [0;9].
- Default: 5.

### dictSize

- Description: The dictionary size.
- Range: [1<<12;1<<27] for `32-bit` version or [1<<12;1<<30] for `64-bit` version.
- Default: 1<<24.

### lc

- Description: The number of high bits of the previous byte to use as a context for literal encoding.
- Range [0;8].
- Default: 3
- Sometimes lc = 4 gives gain for big files.

### lp

- Description: The number of low bits of the dictionary position to include in literal_pos_state.
- Range: [0;4].
- Default: 0.
- It is intended for periodical data when period is equal 2^value (where lp=value). For example, for 32-bit (4 bytes)  periodical data you can use lp=2. Often it's better to set lc=0, if you change lp switch.

### pb

- Description: pb is the number of low bits of the dictionary position to include in pos_state.
- Range: [0;4].
- Default: 2.
- It is intended for periodical data when period is equal 2^value (where lp=value).

### algo

- Description: Sets compression mode.
- Options: 0 = fast, 1 = normal.
- Default: 1.

### fb

- Description: Sets the number of fast bytes for the Deflate/Deflate64 encoder.
- Range: [5;255].
- Default: 128.
- Usually, a big number gives a little bit better compression ratio and a slower compression process. A large fast bytes parameter can significantly increase the compression ratio for files which contain long identical sequences of bytes.

### btMode

- Description: Sets Match Finder for LZMA.
- Options: 0 = hashChain mode, 1 = binTree mode.
- Default: 1.
- Default method is bt4. Algorithms from hc* group don't provide a good compression ratio, but they often work pretty fast in combination with fast mode.

### numHashBytes

- Description: Number of hash bytes. See `mf={MF_ID}` section [here](http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method.htm) for details.
- Options: 2, 3 or 4.
- Default: 4.

### mc

- Description: Sets number of cycles (passes) for match finder.
- Range: [1;1<<30].
- Default: 32.
- If you specify mc = 0, LZMA will use default value. Usually, a big number gives a little bit better compression ratio and slower compression process. For example, mf=HC4 and mc=10000 can provide almost the same compression ratio as mf=BT4.

### writeEndMark

- Description: Option for writing or not writing the end mark.
- Options: 0 - do not write EOPM, 1 - write EOPM.
- Default: 0.

### numThreads

- Description: Number of threads.
- Options: 1 or 2
- Default: 2

### *LZMA2 Options:*

`LZMA2` is modified version of `LZMA`. It provides the following advantages over `LZMA`:

1. Better compression ratio for data than can't be compressed. `LZMA2`
   can store such blocks of data in uncompressed form. Also it
   decompresses such data faster.
2. Better multithreading support. If you compress big file, `LZMA2` can split that file to chunks and compress these chunks in multiple threads.

**Note:** `LZMA2` also supports all `LZMA` parameters, but `lp + lc` cannot be larger than `4`.

### blockSize

- Description: Sets chunk size.
- Default: dictSize * 4.

### numBlockThreads

- Description: Set the number of threads per chunk(block).

### numTotalThreads

- Description: The maximum number of threads `LZMA2` can use.

**Note:** `LZMA2` uses: 1 thread for each chunk in `x1` and `x3` modes; and 2 threads for each chunk in `x5`, `x7` and `x9` modes. If `LZMA2` is set to use only such number of threads required for one chunk, it doesn't split stream to chunks. So you can get different compression ratio for different number of threads.

I think that in order to get more information on this subject you have to study in a more profound way the `LZMA`. There are very few examples on the internet about it and the documentation is quite incomplete.

### *More Info Here:*

http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method.htm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Markov_chain_algorithm

http://linux.die.net/man/1/lzma